# Chevron.Directory.Graph : Public Function IsInGroup(id As String) As Boolean returning false for guest users

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

Our app is using Chevron.Directory.Graph (v 1.8.3.0 for Web Forms). For Guest users, the method Chevron.Directory.Graph.IsInGroup returns false, we checked one of them in Azure AD and found his record in the group for which we check his occurrence. Could anyone, please, help us to solve this problem?

here is the code snippet:

```
If account IsNot Nothing AndAlso
                account.UserType.Equals("Guest") AndAlso
                Not Request.FilePath.Equals("/AppError.aspx") Then
            allowAuthForGuest = If(connector.IsInGroup("Group Name", False), True, False)
        End If
```

when we checked, the IsIngroup takes only one parameter